# how to implement reverse ajax in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, reverse-ajax

I want to implement Reverse AJAX using javascript or jquery framework.

Does Jquery framework support the reverse ajax?

Also what changes would need to be done on the server-side ? I am using Java.

Answer (score 1):

The modern version of reverse Ajax are [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebSockets).

On the Java server side it is available via JSR 356 and implemented by current servlet containers.
In the browser you even don't need JQuery as it supported directly by modern browsers.